# What is the difference between Top and MaxItemCount of CosmosDB in the backend?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I used to find a misusage of `select *` with `MaxItemCount=1` and do not continue to get the next page, in order to get the top item.

At the same time, the result of `select Top 1 *` seems the same as above one.

I tested to know that the first query cost more RU than the second one but I could not understand why and what happened.

It looks like that if we do not fetch the next page, the `MaxItemCount=1` query also return at the first hit. I fail to tell the difference between these two cases.

What is the extra work of `MaxItemCount=1` than select top 1? And how does the pagination really work in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tools control the number of rows returned, but in different layers. They  are orthogonal and may be used in combination.

### Top

See docs for [Keywords - TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/keywords#top) :

> The TOP keyword returns the first N number of query results in an undefined order.

That is the query analyzer does know that only N rows are needed (or 1 in your case). **This specifies the data you want, but does not detail how it will be delivered to client.**

### MaxItemCount

See docs [Pagination - Understanding query executions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#understanding-query-executions)

> You can specify the maximum number of items returned by a query by setting the `MaxItemCount`.

and

> In addition, there are other reasons that the query engine might need to split query results into multiple pages. These include:
>
> - The container was throttled and there weren't available RUs to return more query results
> - The query execution's response was too large
> - The query execution's time was too long
> - It was more efficient for the query engine to return results in additional executions

and

> In some cases, it is also possible that your query may return an empty page of results.

**So, this applies to any query trying to return any number or results, and controls the maximum batch size how the data will be delivered to client.**

#### Why RU cost is different?

I can't see inside cosmosDB nor its RU-pricing model, but it does make sense that `TOP 1` query is cheaper than `MaxItemCount=1`, because:

1. Queries are semantically different. `TOP 1` may be able to optimize the query execution by knowing it only needs the first entry and there is no scan/iteration required. `MAxItemsCount=1` query plan must be able to fetch all  entries matching the predicate.
2. `MaxItemCount=1` query needs to build a continuation token to enable resuming the query execution and/or check for next results, which is extra work. The query does not know whether anyone may want "the next page".

Comment: Thank you Imre! The section under "Why RU cost is different" really answered my confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

**MaxItemCount**
It is set in the FeedOptions. It controls the size of batch result returned by the query. This is used for query pagination.
For more detail please refer [MaxItemCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount?view=azure-dotnet)

**Top**
This will return the first top records returned by the query.

**E.g.:-** `SELECT  TOP  50  *  FROM c`
This query will return top 50 records from the container. When we used `{MaxItemCount = 10}` with above query, then it will return all 50 records but in set of 10 records per page. To get next page records need to use `HasMoreResults`.

**Code Implementation**

```
var options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 };
    var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName),
                        "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM c", options).AsDocumentQuery();
    while (queryable.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var product in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<Product>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product.id);
        }
    }
```

**Model Class (Product.cs)**

```
public record Product(string id, string categoryId, string name, decimal price);
```

Here is sample [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7swF1.png).